# Can't use memcpy on char * attribute as destination - visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, memcpy

I have the following piece of code in *appPOSWebDlg.cpp*:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "afx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Ras.h>
...

//Attribute
char            *site;
...

// Method
int readFile() {

    char * aux;
    int result;

    result = readParameter(hFile, aux);
    if (result == 0) {
        memcpy(site, aux, 256);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the program stops at the *memcpy* line and I'm not sure why. After debugging, I can confirm that the aux parameter is being assigned correctly with the value expected. Furthermore, I even used the *memcpy* inside the *readParameter* method to assign it and had no problem. So why can't I assign that value to attribute *site* using the same method?

Comment: What do you mean by "stops"? Do you get an exception (like a write to an invalid address), does it simply hang, quick-exit from the process with no message? How are `site` and `aux` initialized? Do they contain valid pointers and do those pointers point to memory blocks that are at least 256 byte in size?

Comment: It quick-exit from the process with no message. aux and site are not initialized. They are only declared just as shown in the code. Problem is I can use memcpy in aux but not in site for some reason.

Comment: In that case (assuming `site` is actually a global variable as indicated in the posted snippet) then `site` is initialized by the compiler to be null which `aux` is an indeterminate value.  Neither of those values is valid to be passed to `memcpy()`, and `aux` can't be used for anything until it's explicitly initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "site" pointer is invalid.  You've defined it as a pointer, but, not allocated any space for it, so, your copy command is overlaying some code.  You'll need to allocated the pointer correctly by performing a "new" and a "delete" when you are done.

Comment: So why was I able to use the aux variable in the memcpy method? I didnt allocated any space for it either

Comment: @DanielCalderonMori: if you use uninitialized variables, the system will behave in surprising ways - which can include appearing to not misbehave.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thank you, that was very helpful. rrirower answer was indeed correct. But I had to initialized both variables to make sure the code doesn't behave erratically.